# in c++, getting segmentation fault for this codebase

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

> Consider an n element array,a , where each index i in the array contains a reference to an array of ki integers (where the value of  varies from array to array). See the Explanation section below for a diagram.
>
> Given a, you must answer q queries. Each query is in the format i j,
> where i denotes an index in array  and j denotes an index in the array
> located at a[i]. For each query, find and print the value of element j
> in the array  at location a[i] on a new line.

Problem is described on hackerrank [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/variable-sized-arrays/problem?h_r=profile)
i don't want the solution, i have solved it successfully using double pointers.
please explain why this solution is wrong.
it works fine for its sample test case, and many of custom inputs i have tried,but it fails for large inputs maybe.

> works successfully for sample input .. ie

2 2

3 1 5 4

5 1 2 8 9 3

0 1

1 3

even works for other inputs in this range.
i have tried to use long int as well everywher (in correct form) ,but no use. still getting segmentation fault.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    
    int temp1,temp2,num,queries,numofarrs;

    scanf("%d %d",&numofarrs,&queries);
    int matrix[100000][100000]={0};
    //printf("%d",matrix[1][200]);
    
    for(int i=0;i<numofarrs;i++){
         
        scanf("%d",&num);
        for(int j=0;j<num;j++){
            scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);

        }
        //printf("array %d done",i);
    }
   
    for(int i=0;i<queries;i++){
        
        scanf("%d %d",&temp1,&temp2);
        printf("%d",matrix[temp1][temp2]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int matrix[100000][100000]={0};` it is too much for `stack`.

Comment: To add to what kiran Biradar said, you can use `std::vector` instead here. Also, you probably shouldn't mix C and C++ code like that.

Comment: Use `2d vector` instead of a predefined sized array. It reduces the segment fault error most of the time.

Comment: Thanks for answering..i will definitely learn vectors n try it..

Comment: @kiranBiradar but if that is the case the program shud have given segementation fault for all values bcoz tht matrix is hefty for stack .